# SourceSafe Label Search

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, label

Is there a way to search Microsoft Visual SourceSafe 6.0d for all files tagged with a specific label?

Comment: Got a spite downvote, it's still a valid question.

Comment: upvoted - doesn't deserve a downvote.  good question.  I found it because I have a similar one to ask.  If people do silly downvotes it discourages questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJ had the right idea, but you just need to use the "dir" command instead of get:

```
ss dir -v"LABEL" $\PROJECT -R
```

This will output each file with version that is at that label in the format of:

```
someFile.c;23
someOtherFile.h;3
<filename>;<version>
```

For those interested if you want to quickly tell what the latest version of a file is you can do:

```
ss dir -v. $\PROJECT -R
```

Have a great time!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can search by label, but you can get by label.

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh8hd2cw(VS.80).aspx)

To get a version by label:

1. Make sure that you have set a working folder in Visual SourceSafe Explorer. See How to: Set the Working Folder.
2. Ensure that you have set the history options. See How to: View History.
3. Select the project that contains the file to retrieve.
4. On the Tools menu, click Show History.
5. In the History Options dialog box, select the version of the file to retrieve and click OK.
6. In the History of  dialog box, click Get to retrieve the version of the file that you have chosen.
7. In the Get dialog box, make any additional entries needed and click OK to retrieve the file.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem to be a failure on Microsofts part not to put in a simple search feature on the comments of checkins/checkouts.

I have found this
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Schiott_SourceReport.aspx

It extracts all the comments you want to a text file.

Comment: The app works, it is just an app though, no help file, just tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

You can get by label.
This may not be the same as searching by label.

Sourcesafe accepts a label as a valid version number, so it's the same syntax:

```
ss get -V"my label" $\myproject -R
```

this will get everything labelled `my label` from the `myproject` project.